# match query string variables with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string

The site I am trying to work on is http://northidahocvma.org/2GD/index.php?page=1

So suppose I have URLs with query string parameters like these:

```
/index.php?page=1
```

Using mod_rewrite, how can I redirect them to URLs like these?

`/page/1` or `/1/`

I was given this code but still cant quite figure it out

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+index\.php\?page=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /page/%1? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^page/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Do I type http://northidahocvma.org/2GD/index/1/ or http://northidahocvma.org/2GD/index/page/1/ I tried both and they direct me to  an error page or http://northidahocvma.org/index/page/1/

Comment: You will type: `http://example.com/page/1` in your browser that will be rewritten to `http://example.com/index.php?page=1`

Comment: All I get is a white page with the word error at the top left corner

Comment: Can you check in firebug for what URLs are you getting 404?

Comment: First make sure this .htaccess is enabled by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not?

Comment: it doesnt generate a error but i dont get the same results from last night either

Comment: If it doesn't generate 500 error then it means that your htaccess isn't enabled. Snake it from your apache server config.